# C++, for-loop, saving values to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, input

I'm currently learning the baby steps of C++ and dealing with arrays. There's a program I had to make for a class that takes input from the user, calculating the amount of work hours. The user inputs the amount of days worked, and this value is saved to a variable `amount_days`. There's also a counter for the for-loop, which is `count`.

I have created a for-loop structure that should repeat through the amount of days worked, and take input from the user, saving it all to an array. However, it only takes the first value, and then prints the rest of the output in mass without taking any input from the user.. I have tried to look at my previous work with the for-loop, however, I can't comprehend what I'm doing wrong. After having tried multiple different ways to solve this problem, I haven't come to any solution of sorts, even after changing the initialization of the variables.

The size of the array is 30. I have also tried to make the size of the array the same as `amount_days`, but this changes nothing..

I have a feeling that the problem could be something very small, a rookie mistake, probably. Being new to arrays, I don't know all that well how they interact with the rest of the code.

Here's the code so far:

```
int amount_days = 0;
int numarray[30];
int count;

cout << "The program calculates the total amount of\nwork hours during a given time frame and the average work day length." << endl;
cout << "How many days:" << endl;
cin >> amount_days;

for (int count = 0; count < amount_days; count++) {
    cout << "Input hours of workday " << count + 1 << ": " << endl;
    cin >> numarray[count];
}
    
cout << "Here is where the program should proceed.." << endl;
```

Edit 1:
Hi again, some of you asked for more details. I'm going to add the output I'm getting.

Output:

```
The program calculates the total amount of
work hours during a given time frame and the average work day length.
How many days:
5
Input hours of workday 1: 
5.3
Input hours of workday 2: 
Input hours of workday 3: 
Input hours of workday 4: 
Input hours of workday 5: 
Here is where the program should proceed..
```

Edit 2: It turns out that the problem was the fact that 5.3 is a float value, not an integer. Thanks a lot for the person pointing it out in the comments!

Comment: Did you input a non-numeric character (a letter maybe)?

Comment: details matter. Please tell us exactly what input you typed

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with this code. You should provide an example of an input and a corresponding output.

Comment: You're not trying to enter a real value, like `15.5`, are you?

Comment: fwiw, we don't know yet what is the issue, but most likely it is related to `cin >>` not to the array. For baby steps you could remove the array and see if you can get the same problem

Comment: Hi. I just realized that 5.3 is a float value.. I'll try again. @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: @1b00ff Great. Yeah, that's the problem. You could also make an array of `float` or `double` instead of `int` to support fractions. While you're at it, you could replace the fixed size array with a [`vector<float>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which can grow dynamically. You just [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) values into it.

Comment: Hi Ted. I tried it and works perfectly now! Thanks a lot for pointing that out! @Ted Lyngmo Edit 1: Thanks for the tips. Being new to C++, any help and tips are valuable to me, I'm looking forward to being able to optimize my code and being able to debug it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turns out to be the fact that I had to input `float` values, and the array was initialized as `int`.  A rookie mistake indeed. Thanks for Ted for pointing that out in the comments, I was able to proceed with my little C++ project!

Comment: I suggest you to change the code to `int x; std::cin >> x; numarray[count] = x;` before you fix it. Imho it is important to understand that the actual issue is not the array, but `std::cin >>` failing. `float x; std::cin >> x; numarray[count] = x;` would be fine even if the array stores `int`s